# How do I ask how well someone has reviewed for the midterm?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, american-english, spoken-english

I was asking one of my classmates this question before the midterm. What I said is

> How's the review for the midterm?

Is it how Americans phrase the sentence?

Comment: An American would probably say "How are those midterms coming along?" or "How's the studying going?"

Comment: How's your studying going? Right.